# Installing DHCPD on Arch Linux

Tags: networking, arch-linux, tar, zip, dhcpcd

I've installed Arch Linux today and am a bit of a noob at using it, so when I had done the installation my system would connect too my network fine, but after rebooting it stopped and gave me an error

"Job for netctl@WifiNetwork.service failed  because the control process exited with error code"

I done some research and found out my system does not have a DHCP daemon known as dhcpd

So since my system has no network connection i went on another computer and downloaded the tar file for dhcpd.service from the Arch Linux package website using this link [dhcpd download package](https://roy.marples.name/projects/dhcpcd/)

Since this is a tar file I'm not quite sure how to download it, I've already ran the ./configure file as well as ran "make" and "sudo make install" but the daemon doesn't seem to be running on my system when I checked with **systemctl**. I'd really appreciate if someone could please help me.

Comment: You're better off installing software with pacman in the future. But, what happens when you attempt to run the binary? Did you enable the dhcpd service?

Comment: Well I cant install it with pacman since I have no internet connection

Comment: Just for clarification: a DHCP server daemon `dhcpd` will distribute IP addresses and other network configuration information *to other hosts*. It will not help your system get a network connection if none exists. On the other hand, a DHCP **client** daemon `dhcpcd` (one-letter difference!) would request configuration information from a DHCP server, and use that to configure your network interface(s).

Answer (score 6):

What you want is the dhcpcd package. It’s part of the installation environment and I assume it worked when you installed. To install dhcpcd on your system do the following

1. Boot the installation environment.
2. arch-chroot into your new installation. The Arch installation guide tells you how to do this.
3. In the new installation update packages with `pacman -Syu`
4. Install *dhcpcd* with `pacman -S dhcpcd`
5. Start the service with `sudo systemctl enable dhcpcd` so the `dhcpcd` client will be active after the reboot.
6. Exit the chroot and reboot
7. *Check out the Arch wiki for dhcpcd configuration*

Alternatively there is an article on the Arch wiki that describes how to install a package in a tar ball here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/offline_installation_of_packages

Good luck

Comment: Try to use markdown formatting in order to enhance readability ;-)

Comment: Very helpful answer! Don't forget to start/enable the `dhcpcd` service after configuring it (as mentioned on Arch Wiki). For systemd, you can do it like so: (`sudo`) `systemctl enable dhcpcd`.